# Install type definitions automatically when I install an npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Is there a way to configure `npm` in such a way so that whenever I install a package, it will:

1. Check if it has type definitions inside it
2. If it does not, try to install `@types/PACKAGE` with the `--save-dev` flag

Ideally, I'd like this to happen automatically (as a plugin or something) without writing a shell script that will limit the API. For example, I might write a shell script such as: (note that this doesn't really answer all the requirements)

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install --save $1 && npm install --save-dev @types/$1
```

But this limits me because maybe I want to `--save-dev` both of the packages or want to use some special flags in the command. Also, it creates a dependency on bash which I'd like to avoid.

Alternatively, if there is a way to make a shellscript that won't be limiting in that way, that would be okay too.

Also, the above example doesn't actually check if the package has type definitions already (in which case I *don't* want to download any from `@types`).

Answer (score 5):

Here are some command line utilities that help with this

#### TypeSync

> Install missing TypeScript typings for dependencies in your package.json

- [github](https://github.com/jeffijoe/typesync) - 988 ⭐
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typesync) - 14k/wk

  ```sh
  # installation
  npm i -g typesync
  # usage
  npx typesync
  ```

#### Typed-Install

> Easily install new packages and their types, every time.

- [github](https://github.com/xavdid/typed-install) - 87 ⭐
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-install) - 1k/wk

  ```sh
  # installation
  npm i -g typed-install
  # usage
  typedi lodash
  ```

#### TS-Typie

> A small utility for installing TypeScript definition files using npm

- [github](https://github.com/T-Specht/ts-typie) - 25⭐
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-typie) - 0.3k/wk

  ```sh
  # installation
  npm i -g ts-typie
  # usage
  npx ts-typie
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a CLI utility that does exactly this. Thin layer on top of your package manager of choice.

Check it out at https://github.com/xavdid/typed-install