# Typescript: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-cards'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am totally new to ReactJS and I found myself stuck in the next thing.
I have installed react-cards via npm like this:

```
npm install --save react-cards
```

Installation was ok and I want to import it in my code like this:

```
import Card from 'react-cards';
```

But then I got error saying this:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-cards':'path' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try 'npm install @types/react-cards' if it exists or add a new declaration(.d.ts) file containing 'declare module 'react-cards';'.

I have tried with npm install @types/react-cards but nothing changed.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: how did you create your react project? very unusual to get a typescript error like that unless you're using typescript

Comment: I have created ASP.NET Core MVC app with React trough Visual Studio.

Comment: **See Also**: [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41292559/1366033)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### You're importing an npm packages which lacks **type** information.

In your example, TypeScript doesn't understand the properties of `Card` when imported. TypeScript is not able to detect a type and refers to `any`, which essentially means **untyped.**

For many untyped packages there are `@types` npm packages which add those typings for you. You can find them here: [microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/)

Unfortunately, there's no `@types/react-card` package, but you have options:

1. You could write the typing information for `react-cards` by yourself and save it into a `react-cards.d.ts` file.
2. Disable the warning inside your `tsconfig.json` by setting `"noImplicitAny": false` - Reference : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Further information: [typescript github thread "Importing untyped JS modules"](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/3019)

Comment: So basically if I understand you well, I have decided to work with a package that I can't work with. If I do step 2 I will then get an errors for next 2 lines:

import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';


Sorry, but I am having a strugle working with code tags :)

Comment: I guess that would be a new question :)

Comment: The only thing left I could try is the first thing you have mentioned, but since I am React/Javascript/Typescript newb I really don't have a clue what to do with that.

Comment: Did you install @types/react and @types/react-dom ?

Comment: I am in another movie now. I will check it out when I get home.

Comment: For option 1, where is the react-cards.d.ts file need to be placed?  And are there any updates to tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using VS Code, there's a quick fix suggestion for this you can invoke with <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd> + <kbd>`.`</kbd>

[image: Install missing types]

You can also [automatically add all missing types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64656259/1366033) with **`typesync`** like this:

```sh
npx typesync
```

If the package doesn't have it's own types, and it hasn't been added to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), you'll need to [add a new definitions file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21344)

#### Further Reading

- [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41292559/1366033)
- [Could not find a declaration file for module ''react-materialize'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41462729/1366033)

Comment: This did it for me. Installing in manually did not work, but having VS Code auto install it worked. Thank you!